# Get Domain Name using asp.net in Generic handler page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to get domain name not for remote ip. i have two domain(website). example www.a1.com and www.a2.com. in a2 domain send a request to a1 domain's page like GetRequest.ashx

the example of http request is

```
http://www.a1.com/GetRequest.ashx?username=bala&password=123456
```

in my GetRequest.ashx page example coding

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="Handler" %>

Imports System
Imports System.Web

Public Class GetRequest : Implements IHttpHandler

   Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements     IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

          context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
          Dim username As String = context.Request.QueryString("username")
          Dim password As String = context.Request.QueryString("password")
 **'//Here i need a coding to get requested domain name that is who send the request to my page**

   End Sub

   Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
       Get
         Return False
      End Get
  End Property
End Class
```

i already use the following coding but not solve my problem. because it return ip address. i need domain only not for ip.

```
context.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
context.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_HOST")

Dim domain As String
Dim url As Uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
domain = url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(url.PathAndQuery, String.Empty)
```

the variable domain contain www.a1.com but i need www.a2.com

use google analytics api to solve my problem? then how to use this api can any one explain

Comment: please tell me you are really passing plain text username/password over the wire.

Comment: good. I was afraid that all of SO would come beat you up for that :)

Answer (score 2):

`Page.Request.Url.Host` contains the host name of the url (`www.a1.com` in your example)

If a request on the `www.a2.com` site calls a page on the `www.a1.com` site, the hostname will always be `www.a1.com` since that is the host that was used to call the page.  I recommend passing a query string variable if you need to know that the request originated from `www.a2.com`.

Comment: i need who send the request. not for my website name i need www.a2.com

Comment: www.a2.com send request to www.a1.com so i need www.a2.com name ok.

Comment: ok but security reason i need to check that. when i use domainname as parameter means other user also send same request to my site. how to check whether the request originally send my client or not?

Comment: You could check the HTTP Referrer (`Request.UrlReferrer`).  Assuming you're using a `HttpWebRequest` to call the other url, you can set the `Referrer` property to your www.a2.com url.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Referrer:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Host
```

Inside your code:

```
   Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements     IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

          context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
          Dim username As String = context.Request.QueryString("username")
          Dim password As String = context.Request.QueryString("password")
 **'//Here i need a coding to get requested domain name that is who send the request to my page**
          Dim domain as string = context.Request.UrlReferrer.Host

   End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error?  You should probably check if UrlReferrer is null.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: urlreferrer is not a member of httpcontext

Comment: Dim domain As String = context.Request.UrlReferrer.Host this is also return an error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @bala should be 'Dim domain As String = HTTPContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Host'

Comment: Referer is both optional and filled in by the client.  There are a number of scenaios for it to be missing/incorrect.  It sounds like the OP has one (or more).

Answer (score 0):

You can access the request object through HttpContext, like so:

**EDIT**: Changed to get host name of referring URL

```
string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Host;
```

**EDIT**: UrlReferrer is returning null. Alternative using HTTP_REFERER:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]))
{
    Uri referringUrl = new Uri(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]);
    string referringHostName = referringUrl .Host;
}
```

Comment: sorry this is also return my local domain name that is www.a1.com but i need request sender domain name that is www.a2.com

Comment: the following Error occured "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: @Balachandran Kumar: See edited answer. See if this yields a better result.

Comment: Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"] return empty

Comment: @Balachandran Kumar: Is it possible to direct to this page using Server.Transfer instead? Can't do much if you can't get the referrer to begin with.

Comment: the client send only http request and get response. they did not want to redirect. ok. whether the google analytics api solve my problem?